# Why can't I download the latest version of my package from pip on windows?

Tags: python, windows, pip, binaryfiles

As per the [docs](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/) and [PEP425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/), I have created three pip wheels (one for each windows, linux and mac, with platform specific binaries).

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        27/11/2020     15:08        3099789 pyomexmeta-1.1.20-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
-a----        27/11/2020     15:08        5128081 pyomexmeta-1.1.20-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
-a----        27/11/2020     15:08        2682188 pyomexmeta-1.1.20-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Then I uploaded to pypi using

```
twine upload *
```

The linux version works perfectly:

```
pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
```

but when I try the same command on windows I get

```
(base) PS C:\x> pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyomexmeta==1.1.20 (from versions: 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.14, 1.1.15, 1.1.16, 1.1.17)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyomexmeta==1.1.20
```

Looking at the [pypi listing for my package](https://pypi.org/project/pyomexmeta/#files) shows me that the file I want is there yet it is not being downloaded. My only thought is that the platform tag must be wrong. However PEP425 says

> The platform tag is simply distutils.util.get_platform() with all hyphens - and periods . replaced with underscore _.

so:

```
In [7]: from distutils import util
In [8]: util.get_platform()
Out[8]: 'win-amd64'
```

So why can I not download pyomexmeta-1.1.20 from pip?

### Response to comments

```
(base) PS D:\bcftools> pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from C:\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

Updating pip is a good idea, but alas it does not help me here:

````
(base) PS D:\bcftools> C:\Miniconda\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/28/91f26bd088ce8e22169032100d4260614fc3da435025ff389ef1d396a433/pip-20.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
    Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3.1
Successfully installed pip-20.2.4
(base) PS D:\bcftools> pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyomexmeta==1.1.20 (from versions: 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.14, 1.1.15, 1.1.16, 1.1.17)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyomexmeta==1.1.20```
````

Comment: `pip --version` ?

Comment: `pip --version` == 19.3.1

Comment: I asked for Python version from `pip --version`. It's **Python 3.7**. Your wheels are for Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip --version` shows it's for Python 3.7. Your wheels are for Python 3.8. To install them you need `pip` from Python 3.8. Either

```
pip3.8 install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
```

or

```
python3.8 -m pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
```

PS. I must admit I don't know how to call this in Windows. Never used it.

PPS. From the @Doyousketch2 comment:

```
py -3.8 -m pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20
```

Comment: `py -3.8 -m pip install pyomexmeta==1.1.20` - once you're certain python3.8 is installed

Comment: haha so simple. I just had two wrong conda environment activated. Oops